# How do i traverse a children table that have relationship with multiple tables

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

How do i traverse the child book table when i pass the `grandparent_id` or `parent_id` to look up all the related books both in parent book and child book tables. I'm guessing it is more of a data structure problem. I'm using `Activerecord` to fetch the data from the database.

**Tables structure**

**grand_parent_category**

```
Id      name
2       Math
```

**parent_category**

```
Id      name
1   Algebra book
```

**child_category**

```
Id     name            parent_id.    grandparent_id.   
1.      Calculus book    1                 2
```

The normal way is to traverse the entire child books array and search the `grandparent_id` in the book column.

it would be the same if i choose `parent_id`

**Example**

```
@child_books = child_books.all()
```

Im passing the `@child_books` object to the frontend via Gon

**Javascript**

```
gon.child_books.forEach((book) => {
   If (book.grandparent_id == chosen_grandparent_id) {
      // do something
    } else if book.parent_id == chosen_parent_id {
      // do something
    } else if book.parent_id == children_id
});
```

The result would be. If I choose `grandparent_id` book. Math

1. Grandparent = Math
2. Parent = Algebra, Calculus
3. Children = Additional Math, Discrete Math

   Math

   /

   Algebra

   /                \

   Additional Math Discrete math

But this approach is really slow, if the dataset for child book category is huge let say 5000. Then in order to find the relationship I have to traverse one by one

Another approach I was thinking is to use hash

```
@child_books = child_books.all()
@child_books.index_by(&:id)
```

This will give this result

```
 {           
      1: {id: 1, name: “additional mathematics”, parent_id: 1, grandparent_id: 2 }
      2: {id: 2, name: “discrete mathematics”, parent_id: 1, grandparent_id: 2 }         
  }
```

But this approach can’t be done if I pass the grandparent_id to search for both parent and children books.

What approach should tackle this relationship problem.

Comment: is this a question about using ruby, or using javascript? can you describe what you're trying to achieve, rather than the way you're trying to achieve it? why doesn't the parent know about the grandparent directly?  why is it inferred from the children object?

Comment: and why there are absent sql examples? the problem lays there.

Answer (score 1):

TLDR; You problem is not likely searching through the data but in `// do something` part of your code.

Like @jad said it's very difficult to tell what you are trying to do. What got my attention was when you said `if the dataset for child book category is huge let say 5000` 5000 is tiny. It's barely even a spec in most cases.

What follows is likely not a direct solution to your problem.

```js
// Let setup some test data, nothing too crazy
// 100K Child Books
// 10K Parent Books
// 100 Grand Parent Books

const getRandomInt = (max) => Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(max))
let grand_parent_category = ''.padStart(100, ' ').split('').map((e, id) => ({id, name: `math:${id}`}))
let parent_category = ''.padStart(10000, ' ').split('').map((e, id) => ({id, name: `additional mathematics:${id}`, parent_id: getRandomInt(grand_parent_category.length)}))
let child_books = ''.padStart(100000, ' ').split('').map((e, id) => ({id, name: `child mathematics:${id}`, parent_id: getRandomInt(parent_category.length)}))

// Not counting the setup in the processing time but it's' near instant

let times = {}
// Map our data and create child buckets for easy lookup
times.startSetup = new Date()
const grandParentMap = new Map(grand_parent_category.map(ele => [ele.id, {...ele, children: []}]))
// While mapping parent add the parent to the grandParent for o(1) lookup
const parentMap = new Map(parent_category.map(ele => {
    if (grandParentMap.has(ele.parent_id)) grandParentMap.get(ele.parent_id).children.push(ele.id)
    return [ele.id, {...ele, children: []}]
}))

// While mapping child add the child to the parent for o(1) lookup
const childMap = new Map(child_books.map(ele => {
    if (parentMap.has(ele.parent_id)) parentMap.get(ele.parent_id).children.push(ele.id)
    return [ele.id, ele]
}))

// get a Grand Parent and all his children and grandchildren
const getGrandParent = (grandParentId) => {
    if (!grandParentMap.has(grandParentId)) return
    let grandParent = {...grandParentMap.get(grandParentId)} // shallow clone - safe based on the data given
    grandParent.grandChildren = []

    grandParent.children = grandParent.children.map(parentID => {
        if (!parentMap.has(parentID)) return parentID
        let parent = {...parentMap.get(parentID)} // shallow clone - safe based on the data given
        // iterate over the children and map them into grandParent.grandChildren 
        parent.children.forEach(childID => grandParent.grandChildren.push(childMap.has(childID) ? {...childMap.get(childID)} : childID)) // shallow clone - safe based on the data given
        return parent
    })
    return grandParent
}
times.finishSetup = new Date()

let grandParentId = 42

times.startSearch = new Date()
let results = getGrandParent(grandParentId)
times.finishSearch = new Date()

console.log(`grandParent ${grandParentId} has ${results.children.length} children and ${results.grandChildren.length} grandchildren!`)
console.log(`Setup took ${times.finishSetup - times.startSetup}ms`)
console.log(`Search took ${times.finishSearch - times.startSearch}ms`)


// Sample run
// grandParent 42 has 97 children and 991 grandchildren!
// Setup took 60ms
// Search took 1ms
```

If our data set gets bigger we may want to optimize the setup. I tried 10B children on my local system and it does take around 6 seconds. For sub 1M children this quick solution works well.